# Trimming a function from a file so that the only remaining characters are the function name and parameters

Tags: c#, c, streamreader, streamwriter

I am writing some code that replaces an old C exe. The original c file would read a file and then trim the contents and put them into two new files, a .c and a .h file. I am doing the same thing, but in C#. I have everything figured out, except for how to trim a function down so that only the function name and parameters are put into the .h file. 
This is an example of two of the functions:

```
void
M_SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory(
    Marshal_dataFunc* _argDataFunc_, Marshal_dataFuncArg _argDataFuncArg_, void const* _argSrc_)
{
    SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory const* _src_ = (SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory const*)_argSrc_;

M_uint8_t(_argDataFunc_, _argDataFuncArg_, &_src_->operation);

}

void
MA_SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory(
    Marshal_dataFunc* argDataFunc, Marshal_dataFuncArg argDataFuncArg,
    void const* argSrc, unsigned argNSrcElem)
{

SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory const* src = (SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory const*)argSrc;

for (; argNSrcElem > 0; --argNSrcElem)
{
    M_SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory(argDataFunc, argDataFuncArg, src++);
}
}
```

This would be the expected output:

```
extern void M_SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory(
    Marshal_dataFunc* argDataFunc, Marshal_dataFuncArg argDataFuncArg, void const* argSrc);

extern void MA_SCP_Msg_ClearNVMemory(
    Marshal_dataFunc* argDataFunc, Marshal_dataFuncArg argDataFuncArg,
    void const* argSrc, unsigned argNSrcElem);
```

Currently, the lines of the original file are read in as strings which are assigned through a streamreader and then that string is later written to a streamwriter, so I thought iterating through and finding any strings containing any functions would be a good place to start, and once I have those strings I could edit them somehow. This is what I have so far, finList being the list of strings and fin being the string I will write to the output file.

```
 List<string> finList = new List<string>();
 finList.AddRange(fin.Split('\n'));
     for (int x = 0; x < finList.Count; x++)
         {
             if (finList[x] == "void" || finList[x] == "_Bool" || finList[x] == "bool" || finList[x] == "unsigned")
                 {
                     finList[x] = im not sure what to do here
                     fin = string.Empty;
                 }
         }  

      for (int x = 0; x < finList.Count; x++)
         {
             fin += finList[x];
         }
```

Any direction or help would be much appreciated. I am relatively new to C# and C, so please be patient if I am not using the correct terms for anything. I think ending the string/line of the function at the ")" is what makes the most sense, but I am unsure how to do this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a robust solution, you have to write a C parser and extract all function definitions. Even if you fix the bug in your code it will fail on commented out functions, and then later on all other kinds of corner-cases. Do you have to write that in C#? Use a scripting language! They were made for that.

Comment: I would agree, writing a script seemed like a much easier solution, but the project requires it in C#, its supposed to be a way to learn how to translate C to C#. But thanks for the input. I hadn't even thought about the issue of comments.

Comment: And you probably forgot quoted strings and you make invalid assumptions about the formatting of the code.  You want to parse C code and that requires a parser for C code and such parsers require thousands of lines of code, no matter which language you are using.  The answer to  your question is: Grab a grammar and a lexer file for C and generate a compiler! Everything else is just a hack with illegal assumptions.

Comment: Regexes are probably what you need. Right now, I have no access to my dev system till tomorrow. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution would be something like this:

```
int bracketLevel = 0;
int squareBracketLevel = 0;
var methods = new List<string>();
var isMethodMode = true; // track if we are in method definition or in method body
var isMethod = false; // if we have seen parenthesis in definition
var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < fin.Length; i++)
{
    if (isMethodMode)
    {
        switch (fin[i])
        {
            case '(':
                isMethod = true;
                builder.Append(fin[i]);
                bracketLevel++;
                break;
            case ')':
                builder.Append(fin[i]);
                bracketLevel--;
                break;
            case '{':
                if (bracketLevel > 0) continue;
                if (isMethod)
                {
                    methods.Add(builder.ToString().Trim());
                    builder.Clear();
                    isMethod = false;
                }
                isMethodMode = false;
                squareBracketLevel++;
                break;
            default:
                builder.Append(fin[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (fin[i])
        {
            case '{':
                squareBracketLevel++;
                break;
            case '}':
                squareBracketLevel--;
                if (squareBracketLevel == 0)
                {
                    isMethodMode = true;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Variable `fin` contains loaded C file. While this works for your example there are couple of assumptions:

1. C code is valid (no mismatched parenthesis)
2. No comments which would contain parenthesis (this includes commented out functions as was already noted in comments)
3. Body block does not contain curly braces in string constants

If those assumptions do not hold for you, then you will have to take a look into parser generators which will parse C file and generate abstract syntax tree for you from which you can extract desired information. One example is [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). C grammar is also available at [C.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4).